# When trying to connect to Server I get a Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed error

Tags: node.js, http, alexa-skills-kit, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to send a POST to my server in Cloud9 with node.js. When using Postmaster it works without any problem. I've translated it to node.js and added the http module so my relevant code looks like this:

```
 var http = require("http");
 var options = {
            "method": "POST",
            "hostname": [
                "192.168.153.188"
            ],
            "port": "8080",
            "path": [
                "index.php"
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "text/plain",
                "cache-control": "no-cache",
                "Postman-Token": "19ed6137-291e-45e7-b4c3-04e62c0c89dc"
            }
        };

        var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
            var chunks = [];

            res.on("data", function(chunk) {
                chunks.push(chunk);
            });
            res.on("end", function() {
                var body = Buffer.concat(chunks);
                console.log(body.toString());
            });
        });
        req.end();
```

When sending the post I get following error:

```
/var/lang/bin/node[1]: ../src/tcp_wrap.cc:247:static void node::TCPWrap::Connect(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>&): Assertion `args[1]->IsString()' failed.
 1: node::Abort() [/var/lang/bin/node]
 2: node::Assert(char const* const (*) [4]) [/var/lang/bin/node]
 3: node::TCPWrap::Connect(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/var/lang/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) [/var/lang/bin/node]
 5: 0x55ccab57a28b [/var/lang/bin/node]
 6: 0x55ccab57ac27 [/var/lang/bin/node]
```

I've updated node to `v8.15`, tried `npm i natives` as these are solutions which worked for others but I still get the same error.
I've also tried using request and Unirest instead of http but the connection times out before anything happens with both.